# Postfix block zip files smaller than 20kb

Tags: postfix, regex

I am moving away form sendmail and mime-defang, my current setup rejects zip files smaller than 20kb to try and fight the spreading of ransom-ware attachments. I know its not perfect but it helps.

I dont program and dont understand regex I currently have this in my

```
/etc/postfix/mime_header_checks

/name=[^>]*\.(bat|com|exe|dll|vbs|cmd|docm|dotm|xlm|xlsm|xltm|pptm|potm|ppsm|sldm)/ REJECT We do not allow files of that type because of security concerns
```

That takes care of the unwanted files but not the zip size limit, below id the mime-defang code I need converted into a Postifx friendly command

```
  sub filter ($$$$)
{
  my($entity, $fname, $ext, $type) = @_;

  open F, ">> /tmp/mimedefang.log";
  if (defined($fname))
  {
    if ($fname =~ /zip$/i)
    {
     $size = (stat($entity->bodyhandle->path))[7];
     if ($size < 20000 ) {
       return action_bounce("REJECT ZIP - Zip files less than 20k are not 
accepted $fname $size");
     }
   }

    if ($fname =~ /docm$/i)
    {
      return action_bounce("REJECT DOCM - DOCM files are not accepted $fname $size");
    }

 }
  close F;

}
```

I currently use Clamav, Spamassassin as milters with postscreen for rbl checks the system is Debain 9 with Postfix, Dovecot and postfixadmin.

If there is a better way than the mime_header_checks pls let me know

Comment: You could certainly continue to use MIMEDefang with postfix.

Comment: Part of me moving away from sendmail mimedefang is I dont understand it I know its is very powerful and customization is very good. The current system was put together by someone else I want to change it to something I understand and can support